# How to post data to database from HTML form having manytomany Field in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having form consisting of two input fields having some values, Now I want these values to post in the database having manytomanyfield.
My form is

```
<div class="card-body">
<form action="{% url 'car:user_register' %}" method="POST"  >
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group" >
<input type="text" name="goal" id="goal" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
<input type="text" name="goale" id="goal2" value="">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
</form>
</div>
```

My models.py is

```
class users(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goals)
```

The email password and room values are saving but I want to store the two values in the goal field which is manytomanyfield
My views.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        room = request.POST['room']
        g = goal=request.POST['goal']
        g1 = goal=request.POST['goale']
        user = users(password=password,email=email)
        user.room=rooms.objects.get(pk=room)
        user.goal=goals.objects.get(pk=g)
        user.goal =goals.objects.get(pk=g1)

        user.save()
        user.goal.add(g,g1)
        user.save()
```

Is there any wrong in my views.py it is not storing and please how to store data from form to manytomanyfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are using two strings you have gotten from post request and not actual goal objects to add to user model. for many to many fields you should first create your object (users) and after that you can add objects to m2m fields (in your case goal ) 
try this :

```py
...
     g =request.POST['goal']
     g = g.split(',')
     user = users(password=password,email=email)
     user.room=rooms.objects.get(pk=room)
     goals = goals.objects.filter(pk__in=g)
     user.save()
     user.goal.add(*goals)
```

Comment: glad to help. also it would be better to add try except in case there isn't any object or the input is not correct  i highly recommend to you to use forms

Comment: Ya sure @mahyar

Comment: hey @mahyar if i had 1,2 in the form value can I post those 1 and 2 at a time to the field in views

Comment: is it possible @mahyar in the same form field by using comma can we post data to database

Comment: yes it is possible you can get the values and use values.split(',') to get a list of strings from there filter goal objects by those strings and add to your m2m field

Comment: in the above answer u kept please show in that @mahyar

Comment: something like this .it should be tested

Comment: why did you write pk__in =g why that underscore? @mahyar

Comment: can you please help me out      user.goal.add(*goals)
i got this error at this line                                                                                                              add() argument after * must be an iterable, not ModelBase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204325/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-mahyar).